# Lyx: Change PDF Viewer from Adobe to Mac Preview

Tags: lyx, preview

I am working with Lyx 2.1.2.2 for Mac. I want to change the pdf viewer from adobe to mac's preview. Adobe does not update changes unless I export the file, or close the pdf preview and reload it.

I am not sure what exactly I should change in "Lyx/Preferences" in order to switch the lyx preview.

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73233/lyx-change-pdf-viewer

Comment: Does not seem to work in my case. Perhaps I did something wrong. I will have another go.

Comment: @pschulz the link you gave talks about the same issue, but how do you define the preview app in mac? I followed the steps, but I need to specify the Preview app in the text-field there. I tried to put in `Preview.app` and `Preview`, but it didn't work. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: Sorry, i'm not a mac user, so i don't really know. You could perhaps put in the absolute path of the executive, but that's just a guess. Are you getting some kind of error message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting in preferences->File handling->File formats:

1. format choose "PDF (pdflatex)"
2. set viewer to "open -a Preview"
   It works for me:)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Mac OS Sierra 10.12.6 and LyX Version 2.2.3.

So for configure I install with home brew this recommended programs:

```
brew update
brew cask install basictex
brew cask install texmaker
```

I user the basictex because has everything I need, the mactex is very big.
If you prefer install everything install mactex:

```
brew cask install mactex
```

Go to the menu **LyX > Preferences > File handling > File formats**:

1. format choose "PDF (pdflatex)"
2. set viewer to "open -a Preview"

**Apply, Save and close**.

So on the menu I click on **Tools > Reconfigure**.

Then the LyX reconfigure automatically everything on terminal.
Wait for a while until reconfigure everything.

So after this click on **Document > (Visualize Other formats) > PDF (pdflatex)** or **CMD + R**(*this command isn't accessible everytime so I recommend to get the first option*).

And wait for a while and shows the pdf with Pre-visual.app.
Very nice and I haven't to install the Acrobat Reader Uhull!